# Library not found for -lAFNetworking Xcode issues

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/om-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/om-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSONModel'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/om-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactiveCocoa'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/om-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dom-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SAMKeychain'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/kh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/om-euxqzibzllbcmndwqrgthdeotiro/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sentry'
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Some Solutions I tried , and all of below didn't work which was previously suggested on similar stackoverflow questions

- Opening xcworkspace, yes I am opening that.Not the project
- Restart xcode
- Clean & Build multiple times.
- Deleted pods folder, and installed pods again.
- pod update multiple times
- set Build Active architecture Only to Yes
- Selected my Target, went to "Build Phases" in "Link Binary With Libraries" removed ".a" file of that library. Clean and Build.
- Target -> Build Settings ->Other Linker Flags = $(inherited)
- Target -> Build Settings ->Library Search Path = $(inherited)

Note that libPods-om.a is giving me red whenever i add in target ( choose frameworks and libraries to add)

Worth to note, it runs onreal physical device. but not simulator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had same issue on Xcode 12.4, only on simulators (on device works well).
Solved by adding `arm64` for key `Any iOS Simulator SDK` on `Build Settings < Excluded Archicetures`. Add on

1. Project settings, and
2. Pods settings

[image]

Or, you can try another solution (also worked for me):

1. adding `arm64` for key `Any iOS Simulator SDK` on Project settings
2. add `config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"` on Pod file

Comment: This solution make some progress, Thanks.

Comment: Literally took hours of Googling to finally find this post. It worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Still i couldn't find a solution for this. I flowed many answers. But still i stack with this issue. Des anyone has solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue you are describing. I tried most of the things you mention but none of them worked. In the past I have been 100% successful in running this on the simulator (whenever I was working on a non-UI thing) and needless to say also successful in running it on a real device. Something happened in the last 2 weeks where now neither the simulator nor the real-device can be used.

In the end I just decided to bite the bullet, start from scratch and clone the remote git repository from where the project resides. Note that before doing this I moved my non-working folder into a safe location (Desktop) and cloned the repository into the same location as the non-working used to be.

After that I ran pod install in the folder of the freshly-cloned project and ran it on a physical device. It worked on the first go.
However I still cannot used the simulator. But I'm happy to have gained back the physical device at least.

UPDATE:
SOLUTION FOUND!!

After about a day of researching and trying multiple things. I found a solution here:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10059#issuecomment-693346078

Short summary a new entry is added; it is located in Build Settings->User-Defined->VALID-ARCHS. I deleted this, and now I can run both on simulator and on-device.

Comment: Your last-minute update/edit got my project back up and running. Not sure how you found that, but so glad you did! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Please try delete the Derived Data and pod install again **`/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`**

```
pod install
```

Comment: doesnt work. this issue started after upgrading to xcode 12

Comment: Worth to note, it runs on real physical device. but not simulator

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build Settings
Add new key under User-Defined section

VALID_ARCHS :  armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e x86_64