# library not found for -lAFNetworking Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: error screenshot]I'm having an error with AFNetworking, it's telling me that “library not found for -lAFNetworking“, I'm opening the .xcworkspace file.
you'll find a screenshot about the error.

Comment: For one of your extension, not the main app, no? Is AFNetworking added to that extension? Should that extension knows/uses about AFNetworking? Is the pod (Cocoapods installation) adding it correctly to it?

Comment: yes yes sure everything is good about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it fixed after I tried this answer.

Adding `arm64` at `target` > both in `"yourAppName" and "yourAppName"tests > Build Settings > Excluded Archicetures`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ORpE.png)

The solution is from the post:
[Library not found for -lAFNetworking Xcode issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416794/library-not-found-for-lafnetworking-xcode-issues)